# React Quiz App: Issue with Displaying Correct Score on Quiz Completion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Question:

I am currently working on a React quiz app where users can answer multiple-choice questions and receive feedback on their answers. The app is functioning well for the most part, but I am encountering an issue with the final score display when the quiz is completed.

Here is the relevant portion of the code:

```
// ... (Rest of the imports)

function App() {
  // ... (State variables and initializations)

  const handleSubmission = () => {
    if (selectedOption === questions[currentQuestionIndex].correct && currentQuestionIndex < questions.length - 1) {
      setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1);
      setFeedback('Correct!');
    } else {
      setFeedback('Incorrect!');
    }

    if (currentQuestionIndex < questions.length - 1) {
      setCurrentQuestionIndex(currentQuestionIndex + 1);
    } else {
      setFeedback(`Quiz Complete! You scored ${score} out of ${questions.length}!`);
    }
  };

  // ... (Rest of the component)

  return (
    <div style={style.container}>
      {/* ... (JSX structure) */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The issue arises when the quiz is completed, and the final feedback displays an incorrect score, even if all the answers were correct. I suspect this is due to the asynchronous nature of the setScore function.

I've tried incorporating the useEffect hook to update the feedback after the score changes, and also using the state update callback in setScore, but the problem persists.

Any insights into resolving this issue and ensuring that the final score is accurately displayed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"I suspect this is due to the asynchronous nature of the setScore function"_ - That's right, `score` won't be the new value when you call `setFeedback()`. I imagine you're using `feedback` in your JSX? Rather than trying to construct the feedback string and store it in the state, perhaps try a different approach and write the text you want to show directly in your JSX, then use a boolean to toggle if that feedback is displayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an anti pattern called a derived state, which is setting a state with the change of another state. Why is it a bad thing? Because you are multiplying rerenders and running into desync issues.

You don't need feedback to be a state.

```js
// your states

const isCurrentQuestionCorrect = selectedOption === questions[currentQuestionIndex].correct
const isQuizzCompleted = currentQuestionIndex === questions.length - 1
const feedback = isCurrentQuestionCorrect? "Correct!" : "Incorrect!"

const handleSubmission = () => {
    if (!isQuizzCompleted) {
      setCurrentQuestionIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
       if (isCurrentQuestionCorrect {
             setScore((prevScore) => prevScore + 1);
       }
    }
}

return (
    <div>
        {isQuizzCompleted ? `You scored ${score} out of ${questions.length}!` : feedback}
    </div>
)
```

The implementation is probably wrong but this is the idea.